# JobIntentService not working in doze mode for alarm app

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-doze, jobintentservice

I am making an alarm app for waking up user at an exact time.
I am using JobIntentService (since Android O+ devices don't support background services) for showing a notification alarm like this:-

(AlarmManager -> BroadcastReceiver -> JobIntentService -> ShowNotification).

But now on Android O+ devices  the JobIntentService gets delayed due to the doze mode and the notification alarm is not shown at the exact time.
Even when i use setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() the AlarmManager gets out of doze mode but JobIntentService still gets delayed.

I can't figure out any alternatives for my case/scenario other than the option below:-

Since the user will have to play a game to stop\snooze the alarm,
a **persistent foreground service** will keep playing the alarm until user opens the app(by tapping the foreground service). The alarm will be kept playing until the user plays the game. The foreground service (on-going alarm) will stop once the user is done playing the game.